# Retrieve part of string after underscore

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I know that in Python you can use the array selector to retrieve a certain part of a string, ie `me.name[10:`] to get just the last 10 characters.

but how would you retrieve just the part of a string after an underscore ie `_` using a single expression?
For example if my string is `"stringcharThatChange_myname"`

How would I extract just `'myname'` ? I'm confined to using Python 3.5.1

Comment: See the duplicate, `variable.partition("_")[-1]` or `variable.split("_", 1)[-1]`.

Comment: `me.name[10:]` does *not* get the last 10 characters.

Comment: Also it is not an "array selector". It's called a slice. You can also do `my_list[slice(0, 5, 3)]`. Lastly, as stated by the last comment, the last ten of a sliceable container  is `my_list[-10:]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use split.

```
test_string = "stringcharThatChange_myname"
print(test_string.split('_')[1]) # myname
```

Answer (score 0):

Using split method.

`"this will be excluded_this is kept".split('_')[1]`